# Check OpenGL Version in Swift 3 beta 6

Tags: opengl, version, swift3, xcode8

I would like to check, which OpenGL version is installed on the computer, before I execute OpenGL commands. I wrote a small function to get the NSOpenGLVersion:

```
import OpenGL

func getnsopenglversion () -> String
{
    var major: GLint = 0
    var minor: GLint = 0
    NSOpenGLGetVersion(&major, &minor)
    return ("\(major),\(minor)")
}
```

But this function always returns "1,2" on Yosemite and El Captain, on older Mac Pro 3,1 and new Mac Pro 6,1 or Mac Mini. Always the same.

What I want to get is the OpenGL Version, that means "3,3" or "4,1" or something like this, what is currently installed. I tried the following:

```
let v = glGetString(GL_VERSION)
```

But this will not compile but gets the error saying "Cannot convert the value of type int32 to expected type GLenum".

When I instead convert the GL_EXTENSIONS constant to GLenum with:

```
let v = glGetString(GLenum(GL_EXTENSIONS))
```

It will compile, but I get an exception when running the code. Is there some initialization needed, before calling glGetString?

The question is: I need a small function, which gets the OpenGL version as a string, not the NSOpenGLVersion but the correct OpenGL version of my current hardware. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Until the OpenGL context is created, there is no OpenGL version yet.

Comment: Can you please post a small func which results the OpenGL version, perhaps with using an OpenGL context, which does visually nothing. I think this must be possible but I have no idea how to do this.